# Cordova requirements failed

Tags: android, cordova, requirements

I just start learning cordova, and I can't pass the [requirements step](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#install-pre-requisites-for-building).

Cordova v7.0.1

Android Studio 2.3.3

I'm not sure at all what should I do. I think that I installed everything right.

```
$ cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/AvdManagerCli : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main"
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Means Java 8 bytecode, this means the JVM that gradle is running in is an older version. You should check `java -version` to see what the default JVM is and possibly update the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable so the Java 8 JDK is used.

Comment: That's it. I just follow these steps here for how to add System Variable: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Comment: @ShoneTow Yes, that one from your given atlassian link: "If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name. For example, C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_65" solved my problem! Thanks!